# Executing query with like is not working

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this code:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.customer WHERE mobileNumber Like '%@mobileNumber'";
```

When I execute that code from c#, I got empty results

However when I execute this query in my sql managmenet studio

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.customer WHERE mobileNumber Like '%454545'
```

I got result.

What I am missing?

Comment: How do you execute query from c#? Can you show the code?

Comment: add your entire query code

Comment: Are you using SqlCommand or something else ?

Comment: If the answers below didn't work the problem might be that the parameter
@mobileNumber is changed along the way . 
post your entire script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.customer WHERE mobileNumber Like '%' + @mobileNumber
```

This is assuming @mobileNumber is a parameter containing the value for which you want to search.

Answer (score 2):

It seems from your code that `@mobileNumber` is a parameter. Yet, you place it here as a `string`.

Try putting the `%` in a `string` and the parameter separately unquoted:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.customer WHERE mobileNumber Like '%' + @mobileNumber";
```